# Android Warning: CHECK surface infomation creating=false

Tags: android, surfaceview

When I run my Android application I noticed the following warning in the LogCat window:

```
Tag: SurfaceView
Text: CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false 
sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true 
realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
```

What does this mean? It doesn't seem to cause any issues, but it would be nice to get rid of the warning.

Comment: I also got this warning and my Map is not display

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This mean no problems

Everything is OK

Comment: Do you have any justification for your answer?

Comment: ha ha short and sweet answer :)